# Unable to save or view video when passing over to second UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I have a `UIViewController` where I create a video using `GPUImage`. Now when the video is created I pass over an NSURL to a second `UIViewController` where I display it us a `AVPlayerViewController`.

I display it via the following

```
- (void)showTheVideo {

    /// ----------
    /// Show the video
    /// ----------


    // grab a local URL to our video
    NSURL *videoURL = self.completeMovieURL;

    // create an AVPlayer
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

    // create a player view controller
    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    controller.player = self.player;
    [controller setShowsPlaybackControls:TRUE];
    [controller.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     //controller.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;


    // show the view controller
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.viewVideo addSubview:controller.view];
    controller.view.frame = self.viewVideo.frame;

    [self.player play];

}
```

The problem is that playback on the second UIViewController is really hit and miss. Sometimes it loads the video, other times it does not. I have check the `self.completeMovieURL` and the path is there.

Now to test if the video is actually created, I have tried to save the video on the second controller using

```
[PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:self.completeMovieURL];
```

but I get an error, if however I try to save it on the view controller I created it on it saves fine.

Could someone please explain why I can save the video on the first controller but can't on the second and have issues with playing it?

Answer (score 0):

Save your video using below code:

```html
#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAsset.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAssetsLibrary.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAssetRepresentation.h>

- (void)writeToAlbum:(NSURL *)outputFileURL{
    self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    if ([_library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
    {
        [_library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                     completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   //  [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"failed"];
                 });
                 NSLog(@"fail to saved: %@", error);
             }else{
                 NSLog(@"saved");
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   //  [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"saved"];
                 });
             }
         }];
    }}
```